# Referring to: How to Use LLIST *mylist[N];

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

This does work

```
LLIST *mylist[10] = {NULL};
```

But would if I wanted to do this I get errors:

```
int x=10; 

LLIST *mylist[x] = {NULL};
```

`x` can be any value I'm setting it to 10 for the time being.  `x` is going to be used as a counter.

Comment: Shouldn't it btw be NULL instead of {NULL} ?

Comment: no, {NULL} is a legitimate way to initialize the array with nulls.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Is it also a C99 feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for variable length arrays (which your second example uses) came in the C99 standard, which your compiler may not support.

For gcc, you should pass the `-std=c99` option when compiling.

Comment: I use a make file that i run to compile

Comment: In that case you should modify the `CFLAGS` and add `-std=c99`.

Comment: @MRP: Then set the CFLAGS environment variable to include `-std=c99`

Comment: I'm new using c and compiling

Comment: here is my make file

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
#LIBS=-lreadline -lm
OBJS=llist.o myprogram.o
INCLUDES=llist.h

all: $(OBJS) 
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o myprogram

.c.o: $*.h $(INCLUDES)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c

clean: 
 rm -f *.o myprogram

Comment: i wish there was a better way to post it

Comment: Would i just add then CFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c99

Comment: Yupp, it works right? Or do you still get the same compiler errors?

Comment: and that means, the compiler don't know how long it should initialize your array at _compile time_, then you will need to do

#include <strings.h>
...
bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

Comment: i have #include <strings.n> i never heard of the bzero function.. My original thought when starting this program it would be easier doing a link list of link lists.. defining an array size of an arbitrary number makes no sense.

Comment: Is this then the correct way to implement it:
LLIST *mylist[] = {NULL};
bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

Comment: it does compile soo thats good news I just dont know if it works the same

Comment: LLIST *mylist[] = {NULL}; is the same as writing LLIST *mylist[1] = {NULL};

you should change LLIST *mylist[] = {NULL}; to LLIST *mylist[x]; and then do your bzero. otherwise you will have to allocate the array yourself with ex. malloc(3)

Comment: so I have... int x;  LLIST *mylist[x]; x=10; then  bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

Comment: int x = 10; LLIST *mylist[x]; then bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

Otherwise the x will have a random value when it is to decide the size of the mylist array.